# How to redirect to website in sub directory of Yii1 project?

Tags: yii1.x

Am setting up website inside sub directory of Yii1 project which causing url conflict, which Yii1 think /test is a controller.

for example:

http://www.example.com/ (main website)
http://www.example.com/test/ (sub website)

I have tried with htaccess rules and didn't work.

RewriteRule ^$ /test [L,R=301]

I expect the output to show website in sub directory

http://www.example.com/test/ (sub website)

Answer (score 0):

Issue found, it was htaccess in /test/ project:

```
enter code he<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /test/index.php [L]
```

re